# sed: Replace part of a line

Tags: sed

How can one replace a part of a line with sed?

The line

```
DBSERVERNAME     xxx
```

should be replaced to:

```
DBSERVERNAME     yyy
```

The value xxx can vary and there are two tabs between dbservername and the value. This name-value pair is one of many from a configuration file.

I tried with the following backreference:

```
echo "DBSERVERNAME    xxx" | sed -rne 's/\(dbservername\)[[:blank:]]+\([[:alpha:]]+\)/\1 yyy/gip'
```

and that resulted in an error: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS.

Whats wrong with the expression? Using GNU sed.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This works:

```
sed -rne 's/(dbservername)\s+\w+/\1 yyy/gip'
```

(When you use the -r option, you don't have to escape the parens.)

Bit of explanation:

- `-r` is extended regular expressions - makes a difference to how the regex is written.
- `-n` does not print unless specified - `sed` prints by default otherwise,
- `-e` means what follows it is an expression. Let's break the expression down:

  - `s///` is the command for search-replace, and what's between the first pair is the regex to match, and the second pair the replacement,
  - `gip`, which follows the search replace command; `g` means global, i.e., every match instead of just the first will be replaced in a line; `i` is case-insensitivity; `p` means print when done (remember the `-n` flag from earlier!),
  - The brackets represent a match part, which will come up later. So `dbservername` is the first match part,
  - `\s` is whitespace, `+` means one or more (vs `*`, zero or more) occurrences,
  - `\w` is a word, that is any letter, digit or underscore,
  - `\1` is a special expression for GNU `sed` that prints the first bracketed match in the accompanying search.

Comment: I know you guys have a lot experience in shell commands...but please care the aspiring linux noobs wherever possible.... everything inside `''` needs to be explained....or I have to go through the whole [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)

Comment: Note that with `sed -n` and `/p` in the pattern, this will only print the changed lines (filtering out the rest of the file) which I'm not sure is what the questioner wanted.  (Versus `sed -rpe 's/.../.../gi` which would print every line, with just the matches changed.)

Answer (score 10):

Others have already mentioned the escaping of parentheses, but why do you need a back reference at all, if the first part of the line is constant?

You could simply do

```
sed -e 's/dbservername.*$/dbservername yyy/g'
```

Comment: Good point! I had just learnt about using regexps + sed and mind just decided 'regexp' on seeing this particular task, then as 'jwz' said 'I had two problems' (though not directly due to the regexps) :)

Comment: This gets my vote because it's the simplest solution to a simple problem. Using a backreference would save you from mistyping the two copies of `dbservername`. It's obvious here, but when I modify postgresql.conf in sed I find it hard to see at a glance whether I typed `listen_address` or `listen_addresses` (postgresql.conf). Both look plausible, but only one is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You're escaping your ( and ). I'm pretty sure you don't need to do that. Try:

```
sed -rne 's/(dbservername)[[:blank:]]+\([[:alpha:]]+\)/\1 yyy/gip'
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be escaping things when you use single quotes. ie.

```
echo "DBSERVERNAME    xxx" | sed -rne 's/(dbservername[[:blank:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)/\1 yyy/gip'
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be escaping your parens.  Try:

```
echo "DBSERVERNAME    xxx" | sed -rne 's/(dbservername)[[:blank:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)/\1 yyy/gip'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo "DBSERVERNAME     xxx" | sed 's/\S*$/yyy/'
DBSERVERNAME     yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`sed -re 's/DBSERVERNAME[ \t]*([^\S]+)/\yyy/ig' temp.txt`

or this

`awk '{if($1=="DBSERVERNAME") $2 ="YYY"} {print $0;}' temp.txt`