# replace text in UNIX SED

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have text1.txt that contains

```
<this can be anything, any number of line - no hardcoded>
<this can be anything, any number of line - no hardcoded>
     param1=<this can be any value - no hardcoded>
<this can be anything, any number of line - no hardcoded>
<this can be anything, any number of line - no hardcoded>
```

And I would like to replace this part **this can be any value - no hardcoded** with **abc**

What should be the right SED command?
Note that due to environment restriction i don't have the flexibility to use any language such as perl, python, or ruby ~ and can only use Unix command.
And no hardcoded except for **param1**

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074450/sed-replace-part-of-a-line) may help.

Comment: How about all the sample values in comment?

Comment: @shiplu Could you clarify what constitutes a comment, as per OP's question `text1.txt` is a normal text file, so anything could indicate a comment?

Comment: I asked the question to OP to clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invocation you want is

```
sed -e 's/param1=.*/param1=abc/' text1.txt
```

Comment: This might change all the sample values in comment. No?

Comment: If you mean that the six-character sequence `param1=` will always have the rest of the characters on its line repleced with `abc` even if it appears in a "comment" then yes.  But the OP never said anything about comments.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like `s/<.\+>$/<abc>/`:

```
$ cat test1.txt

<this can be anything, any number of line - no hardcoded>
<this can be anything, any number of line - no hardcoded>
     param1=<this can be any value - no hardcoded>
<this can be anything, any number of line - no hardcoded>
<this can be anything, any number of line - no hardcoded>

$ sed 's/<.\+>$/<abc>/' test1.txt

<abc>
<abc>
     param1=<abc>
<abc>
<abc>
```