# Replace everyting after every time different string

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

Want to change everything after security.server.ip=* with the result ip from the second grep.

First Grep:

```
cat admin.conf|grep security.server.ip|grep -v ^#
```

Result:

```
security.server.ip=10.10.1.2
```

Second Grep:

```
cat /etc/hosts|grep -i admin-server|head -1|awk '{ print $1}
```

Result:

```
10.10.1.2
```

Sometimes security.server.ip will be different on admin.conf and I'm wondering how to replace it with one command which will catch IP address form second grep and replace it in the first one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed: Replace part of a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074450/sed-replace-part-of-a-line). Just store the values in a variable and then use answers in that question.

Comment: Just use awk for all of it, the cat at the start is also completely pointless as the commands take files as arguments

Comment: I'm not able to figure it out how to do it, even the below examples not work!

Comment: Write your question more coherently and you will get better answers, give expected output and try to explain what you actually want better as it is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
IP=$(exec grep -i admin-server /etc/hosts | awk '{ print $1; exit }')
sed -i "/^security\.server\.ip=/s|=.*|=$IP|" admin.conf
```

Comment: Is it possible that IP variable to be included in sed, is there option which permit execute of bash commands?

Comment: What do you mean the IP variable to be included in sed? Isn't my script doing that already?

Comment: That script is not working as expected I get some error: sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @KalinBorisov Sorry. I now added the terminating delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You could save it in a variable:

```
NEWIP=`grep -i admin-server /etc/hosts|head -1|awk '{ print $1}'` \
sed -i "s/^security\.server\.ip=[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/security\.server\.ip=$NEWIP/" admin.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for inplace editing, nextfile, and gensub():

```
gawk -i inplace '
    NR==FNR{ if (tolower($0) ~ /admin-server/) { ip=$1; nextfile } next }
    { $0=gensub(/(security\.server\.ip=).*/,"\\1"ip,""); print }
' /etc/hosts admin.conf
```