# Sed appears to work but file doesn't change

Tags: bash, sed

Based on: [sed: Replace part of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074450/sed-replace-part-of-a-line)

I want to modify my `sysctl.conf` file. The line which contains `PermitTunnel something` must be changed to `PermitTunnel point-to-point`.

So using as one man said in the post before, I would use:

```
sed -e 's/PermitTunnel.*$/PermitTunnel point-to-point/g'
```

Including at the end of the line my file.

Since `-n` is not used, I guess I'm expected to receive at standar output the result of my operation. Then I executed it and get (notice I'm using `-2-` instead of `-to-` just in order to see if I can modify the file as I want, because the file already have the desired line at this case):

```
root@debian:/home/dit# sed -e 's/PermitTunnel.*$/PermitTunnel point-2-point/g'/etc/sysctl.conf 
PermitTunnel point-2-point
```

But then I do:

```
root@debian:/home/dit# cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep PermitTunnel
PermitTunnel point-to-point
```

So as you can see, the file has not changed. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You command take sysctl.conf as input, and stdout as output. You have to use the `-i` option to replace "in place"

```
sed -i -e 's/PermitTunnel.*$/PermitTunnel point-2-point/g'/etc/sysctl.conf
```

You can also specify a suffix for a backup file:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/PermitTunnel.*$/PermitTunnel point-2-point/g'/etc/sysctl.conf
```

From man sed:

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
     edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
```

---

Alternatively, you can redirect stdout to a new file:

```
sed -e 's/PermitTunnel.*$/PermitTunnel point-2-point/g'/etc/sysctl.conf > /etc/sysctl.conf.new
```

Comment: For information, in some versions of sed (BSD, in particular), the argument of the `-i` flag is mandatory, not optional.