# Replace before a pattern sed

Tags: replace, sed

I need something similar to : [sed: Replace part of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074450/sed-replace-part-of-a-line)

I have an IPaddres that as the pattern, I need to replace string before it.

Sample :

```
#stuff SSIPaddress
```

Needs to be

```
stuff SIPaddress
```

Ideas or at least how to turn the one from the link to work for me :)

Comment: If you have tabular data, you might find that awk is a better tool for this kind of task.

Comment: You just  want to replace `#stuff SS` with `stuff S` ?

Comment: The question is too ambiguous without several concrete example lines of things that should or should not change.  I don't think it's as complicated as you suggest in your answer, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example :

```
sed 's/^#stuff SS\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\(.*\)/stuff S\1\3/' <<< "#stuff SS1.2.3.4"
```

outputs :

```
stuff S1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeGnome, you're right, but let me show what I tried:

[sed: Replace part of a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074450/sed-replace-part-of-a-line) -this replaces after a pattern.

I tried to reverse the string to work for me ( replace after pattern, right )

```
echo “`grep "SS" file | sed -re '/([0-9]{1,3}\.){4}/p' 
| grep -v drama`” | rev | sed -i …|rev
```

Problem with this idea is, it prints a duplicate of the matched line back in the file && cant double pipe sed -i without a file at the end ( err sed: no input file)

The winning code, after a lot of sed madness

```
sed -ri 'drama/! { /SS/ s/SS/S/;s/#// } '  file
```

due to

```
#*.* SSdrama:123
#*.* SSIP
```

" Do not match drama, in a line with SS pattern, for all else ( only one ocurrence in my sample)  sed replace SS with S and # with '';Note that I didn't have to match the IP at the end at all.